# Crash report prints full path to file

Tags: macos, realm

I've got a crash report for my macOS app. The crash is related to Realm and schema version.
But it also states the exact file/line of the crash, along with the full path to it (including my name):

> Application Specific Information: Fatal error: 'try!' expression
>   unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Provided
>   schema version 0 is less than last set version 4."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Provided schema version 0 is less
>   than last set version 4., Error Code=1}: file
>   /Users/myNameHere/workspace/myProg/myApp/myVC/Utils/myFile.swift, line
>   40

It's the first time I see the full path, including my username at a crash report. I don't want this path to be printed. Can I change it somehow?

Comment: It won't show that to other people when they run it on their own devices, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Is that the report showing in the console?

Comment: I got this report from another person at my company, which run the app on his device.
It's not from the Console, I'll ask how he got it, but I think he just pressed the report button when the app crashed and he got this report.

Comment: Ok, That's the macOS crash report that's sent to Apple/developer. Why wouldn't you want to collect data about your app crashing? The user will see their name in the path  so that's not big deal and what's the problem with seeing the path?

Comment: This is the reason I'm asking - the user (a co-worker) saw *my* name at this path, not his name. It's the first time I encountered this issue.

Comment: That's a good one. Do you have anything hard-coded in your app? This path is a bit odd */Users/myNameHere/workspace* which is why I am asking.

Comment: I agree it's a very weird path, but I don't have anything hard-coded.

Comment: Are you copying one realm to another or are you shipping the app with a bundled Realm? I can duplicate the error but when I run the app under different user accounts, the path changes depending on which account it. When I run it on my Mac with the app on the desktop, I get *file /Users/jay/Desktop/TestApp/TestApp/AppDelegate.swift, line 49* and on my wife's Mac I get *file /Users/wife/...*. Do you have sandboxing on or off?

Comment: I'm shipping the app with a bundled Realm, and sandbox is on

Comment: To clarify, there's nothing in your entire project that refers to a path of any kind. Like `Bundle.main.path` or perhaps the code surrounding where the bundled Realm is read in in? Or maybe where the Realm is stored to disk? I've gone through every gyration I can think of to duplicate that issue and the path always resolves to the current user name in our testing.

Comment: No, nothing at all. And as I said it's the first time I saw this issue. Maybe it would be better to investigate it only if it will reproduce. And thanks for all your time & effort!